# set number of threads open Mp (c++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am working on visual studio 2012 and trying to use several threads on a very simple hello word example :

```
#include <omp.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel 
    printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads()); 
}
```

But the result I got is :

```
Hello from thread 0, nthreads 1
```

Why can't I have 4 threads ?

Comment: Your code works fine. This must be an environment issue. Have you consulted the documentation of your compiler?

Comment: no I didn't, but as I am working on visual studio I assumed it has a standard configuration...

Comment: I suggest you enable OpenMP in MSVC under C++/Language/OpenMP support or add `/openmp` to the command line.